# How to render only shadow instead of an object?

Tags: eevee-render-engine

In Blender internal render, that has been deprecated, there was an option for material to render only shadow that is cast on an object, not the object itself. Is there a way to do the same in the Eeevee render in Blender 2.9x ?

EDIT: In cycles, there is an option "Shadow catcher" under the object's visibility settings. What I would like is similar option or solution in Eevee.

Comment: You should change your question, because like this you are asking two totally different things. Or you should delete your EDIT part. Or delete all this question and ask a new one focused on your part in EDIT. Like now it is messy. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eevee

### Render Only Shadow instead of Object

- In *Principle BSDF* set *Alpha* zero
- and under *Material Properties > Settings > Blend Mode >* **Alpha Clip**

[image]

Reaction on your EDIT:

### Shadow Catcher

- **Shader to RGB** with some tweaking in *Color Ramp*
- and under *Material Properties > Settings > Blend Mode* > **Alpha Blend**

[image: screen]

Comment: almost looks like you have an AMD gpu issue, lol.

Comment: ...and shadow mode: opaque, else it won't work